# Concatenar dois Dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Preciso gerar um novo dataframe com a concatenação de dois dataframes. 
O seguinte código funciona, porém demora muito pra rodar.

```
df_concatena = pd.DataFrame()

for x in range(len(df)):
    for y in range(len(data)):
        df_concatena = df_concatena.append(pd.concat([df.iloc[x], data.iloc[y]]), ignore_index=True)
```

Tentei usar o apply mas não tive sucesso.

Exemplo df: 
df.shape -> 81476

```
'Valor','Clase','Tempo'
44.99  , 'A'   , 5
61.49  , 'B'   , 8
102.24 , 'C'   , 6
51.07  , 'B'   , 8
32.78  , 'B'   , 12
30.05  , 'B'   , 10
```

Exemplo data:
data.shape -> 21

```
'Dia_Semana','Faixa'
    0       , 'A'
    0       , 'B'  
    0       , 'C'  
    1       , 'A'  
    1       , 'B'  
    1       , 'C'
```

Para cada linha do df, preciso adicionar todas as 21 linhas do data.

Comment: Pode nos dar um exemplo de como são `df` e `data`?

Comment: Boa tade, @N.Peterson. Se o seu objetivo é apenas fazer uma concatenação de dataframes pandas, sugiro a função "concat" do módulo. A documentação está aqui: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa fazer o produto do cartesiano nesses dois `dataframes`. Uma opção seria usar o `merge`, porem é preciso criar uma chave para fazer a ligação desses dois `dataframes`, no caso chame ela de `k`. E no final da operação só da um `drop` nessa chave. segue código de exemplo abaixo:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['C0', 'C1'],
                      'D': ['D0', 'D1']})

df1['k'] = 1
df2['k'] = 1

resultado = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['k'])

resultado = resultado.drop(["k"],axis=1)
print(resultado.head(100))

##########
resultado
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A0  B0  C1  D1
2  A1  B1  C0  D0
3  A1  B1  C1  D1
4  A2  B2  C0  D0
5  A2  B2  C1  D1
6  A3  B3  C0  D0
7  A3  B3  C1  D1
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra opção é usar o `pd.concat`:

```
dfA = pd.read_csv('yourfile_A.csv')
dfB = pd.read_csv('yourfile_B.csv')

df = pd.concat([dfA, dfB], axis=1)
```

axis = 0 ou axis = 1 define se vc quer juntar os dataframes por linha (igual o `append`) ou por coluna.